What is the best way of carrying currency while travelling to Singapore?
We are travelling from India to Singapore, and would like to know the best way to carry currency.

Is it best to just carry cash in SGD, Singapore Dollars?
Is is good to have a forex card, and withdraw money in Singapore through automated teller machine (ATM)?
Currently I do not hold any credit card, but have international debit card, is is a good option as well?
Also, as per my research one can easily use digital payment apps for transactions, so nothing to worry about?


Does the Forex card you're considering also allow POS payments, or is it only for withdrawing cash at ATMs?

Long-term Singapore resident here. The easiest option will be using your debit card, if it's Visa/MasterCard compatible it will be accepted pretty much everywhere. Do check your bank's foreign exchange fees though.
The one place that's still effectively cash only is hawker centres, so you'll want to have some cash for that (around $10/person/meal).  Either withdraw from an ATM or exchange in person, you can get decent rates for rupees especially near Little India (Mustafa etc).
Digital payments are a bit of a mess with tons of competing apps, and you'll have trouble moving money in/out without a Sg bank account. For a short tourist trip I wouldn't bother, debit card plus cash will cover 100% of your needs.
You can also use the contactless debit card on public transport. No need to take a separate MRT card.

Thank you @lambshaanxy, does the MRT accept international debit cards(Visa/Master Card)? Or we need credit cards only?

@YogeshChavan If it has the contactless symbol, it's supported, both credit and debit. You will need one card per person though.

@YogeshChavan: There's a $0.60 per day fee. Also, some cards issued by ANZ and HSBC don't work. See https://www.simplygo.com.sg/faqs

Just to note (since most Singapore residents are not aware of this) the $0.60 daily fee applies to foreign cards used on MRT. So if you are staying a while in Singapore then an MRT card can be the best option. And obviously this doubly applies if your own bank/credit card applies a foreign transaction charge.
